# Confusion in testing RPC and curl

Tags: json-rpc, testnet

Please forgive the ignorance of a beginner.

I started a test network (`bitcoind -testnet rpcuser=zz`)

When I run `bitcoin-cli -testnet getbestblockhash`, everything works fine and I get the correct message, but when I run

```
curl --user zz --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id": "curltest", "method": "getbestblockhash", "params": []}' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:18332/
```

And I can't get any feedback.

Can anyone help me with the reason for this?

Is curltest necessary to change **"id":"curltest"** when I am starting the main network (`bitcoind rpcuser=zz`)?

Should I follow the port shown at https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/getbestblockhash.html for the run, or should it depend on what I'm running on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Unable to start HTTP server. See debug log for details](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/118921/error-unable-to-start-http-server-see-debug-log-for-details). In my answer there I show how to check port numbers and how to perform a series of basic tests using curl.